# ubuntu 13.04 and Kubuntu and windows 8 boot problem

Tags: 13.04

i was installing windows 8
then i installed ubuntu 13.04 and Burg for boot loader
and everything was going great
then i installed Kubuntu and it changed the boot but still works

and last thing which caused the problem,i used Easy BCD on windows 7 to change
the boot loader to the windows 8`s boot loader
but it messed up everything,
only windows 8 shows and i tried to add entries " Ubuntu and Kubuntu " but it does not work when i select on start up
 i tried many things using live cd of ubuntu and kubuntu but nothing work.
so Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want EasyBCD. I do not know that, but some do use it. It has to compromise grub2's boot loader to work. You have to force grub2 to install into a partition's boot sector (PBR) which means it uses blocklists or hard coded addresses to find the rest of grub in the install. If any of those files are updated then the address may be wrong & you have to reinstall grub. 
But you have to install Ubuntu's grub2 boot loader to the PBR of Ubuntu and Kubuntu's to the PBR of Kubuntu. (actually only one required as either grub will offer to boot everything.)

If you really want EasyBCD:

http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu

Whichever install you install last is the boot loader that goes into the MBR of the hard drive and will be the one used to boot. Any other boot loader must be chain loaded to another boot loader or grub can find kernels and boot those also.

How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Reinstall grub2 - Short version & full chroot version

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling GRUB2

I am not sure that burg has been maintained for a while, so it may not work with newer systems.